# codeception with YII2 radio button

Tags: radio-button, yii2, codeception

I have an issue with radio field.

```
echo $form->field($member_model, ‘gender’)->radio(array(‘label’=>”,’value’=>’M’,’id’=>’left’))->label(‘Male’);
echo $form->field($member_model, ‘gender’)->radio(array(‘label’=>”,’value’=>’F’,’id’=>’right’))->label(‘Female’);
```

I have the above radio fields with Male selected by default. And in my acceptance code:
`$this->actor->selectOption(‘input[name=”Membersinfo[gender]”]’, ‘M’);`

But,

> Couldn’t select option “input[name=”Membersinfo[gender]”]”,”M”:
>   InvalidArgumentException: Input “Membersinfo[gender]” cannot take “M” as
>   a value (possible values: F)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code help you!

```
$this->actor->selectOption('//input[@name="Membersinfo[gender]"]', 'M');
```

I tested with this sample listed bellow:

```
$I->selectOption('//input[@name="Membersinfo[gender]"]', 'M');
```